# Python: Replacing url with title

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have written this code to replace urls with their titles. It does replace urls with titles as required but it prints their titles in next line.

twfile.txt contains these lines:

```
link1 http://t.co/HvKkwR1c
no link line
```

Output tw2file:

```
link1
Instagram
no link line
```

but i want output in this form:

```
link1 Instagram
no link line
```

What should i do?

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

output = open('tw2file.txt','w')

with open('twfile.txt','r') as inputf:
    for line in inputf:
        try:
            list1 = line.split(' ')
            for i in range(len(list1)):

                if "http" in list1[i]:
                    ##print list1[i]
                    response = urllib.urlopen(list1[i])
                    html = response.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                    list1[i] = soup.html.head.title
                    ##print list1[i]


                    list1[i] = ''.join(ch for ch in list1[i])
                else:
                    list1[i] = ''.join(ch for ch in list1[i])
            line = ' '.join(list1)
            print line
            output.write(line)
        except:
            pass


inputf.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: (see here, here, and here)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

with open('twfile.txt','r') as inputf, open('tw2file.txt','w') as output:
    for line in inputf:
        try:
            list1 = line.split(' ')
            for i in range(len(list1)):
                if "http" in list1[i]:
                    response = urllib.urlopen(list1[i])
                    html = response.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                    list1[i] = soup.html.head.title
                    list1[i] = ''.join(ch for ch in list1[i]).strip() # here
                else:
                    list1[i] = ''.join(ch for ch in list1[i]).strip() # here
            line = ' '.join(list1)
            print line
            output.write('{}\n'.format(line))  # here
        except:
            pass
```

BTW, you are using Python `2.7.x +`, two `open`s expressed in the same `with` clause. Also their `close`s are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding the content written to a file**

```
fileobject = open("bar", 'w' )
fileobject.write("Hello, World\n") # newline is inserted by '\n'
fileobject.close()
```

**Regarding console output**

Change  `print line` to `print line,`

Python writes the '\n' character at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma.

Comment: it's not affecting the output

Comment: why are you printing 2 times ? print line and output.write(line)?

Comment: `print` seems for `console`. the other seems for `file`